# VBA - Trigger event with excel solver

Tags: vba, excel, triggers, solver

I have found plenty of resources on how to start the [`excel solver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/using-the-solver-vba-functions) with a macro. How about the other way around? **Is there a possiblity to start a macro triggered by the execution of the excel solver?**

I know that macros can be triggered for example through the change of values in cells. A workaround could be to go for a cell, which the solver will manipulate and start the macro whenever something changes there.

My goal is to automatically document the use of the solver within a worksheet, extracting information about the usage. For example through the `SolverSolve` and `SolverGet` functions.

Comment: It isn't the comment you've wished to see, but since you are going to use macros anyway, do you realy need solver?

Comment: Yes, my vba skills can't really replace the build in optimization of excel solver. I however went over to start the solver with a button, which at the same time triggers the rest of the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 200 Then
            Call YourMacroName
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Of course you will NOT reprogram, or replace, Solver, in any way.  There was a lot of brain power that went into creating it.  Why reinvent the wheel?

http://ask.brothersoft.com/the-history-of-excel-solver-147811.html